# Retrieve Spinner Selected Item To Use in Condition Statement

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I'm able to save my spinner selected item states. I'm just having trouble sending and retrieving selected items to use in if statement in next activity.

I know I must use sharedpreferences, but I'm having a bit trouble when it comes to spinner items.

Here's my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);



    LastSelectedItem = getSharedPreferences("PriorSelected", MODE_PRIVATE);

    go_back_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_back_btn);
    themeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.themeSpinner);


    go_back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LastSelectedItem = getSharedPreferences("PriorSelected", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = LastSelectedItem.edit();
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    int LastSelection = LastSelectedItem.getInt("LastSelection", 0);
    editor = LastSelectedItem.edit();


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> themeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(settings.this, R.array.theme_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    themeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    themeSpinner.setAdapter(themeAdapter);
    themeSpinner.setSelection(LastSelection);


    themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            editor.putInt("LastSelection", position).apply();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Currently what do you get from here and what do you expect?

Comment: So you are creating `intent` in moment when you are clicking on `go back button` and also at this point you are creating your preferences, which I assume should be created earlier, and then eventually `put` required data to `editor` or `putExtras` to intent and `startActivity` on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine, I found the answer.

```
// send data to next activity
    go_back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int Myposition = themeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("LastSelection", Myposition);
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Below is code to retrieve on next activity:

```
//    Retrieve and implement conditional statement
private void ToggleTheme() {
    final SharedPreferences LastSelectedItem = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PriorSelected", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int LastSelection = LastSelectedItem.getInt("LastSelection", 0);
    if (LastSelection == 1) {
        homebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_theme_buttons);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("app_pref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

 themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  //To save
editor.putInt("position",position);
editor.commit();


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });



   //To retrieve in next activity
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("app_pref", 0);
   int snowDensity = settings.getInt("position", -1); //0 is the default value
```

instead of share preference you can store value to int and pass it to next activity.

```
 int position=-1;   

 themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                position=position;


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                position=-1;
            }
        });


       go_back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), home.class);
               intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Second Activity:**

```
int position= getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
```